# How to correct a Roth conversion pro-rata rule mistake on form 8606?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-conversion, form-8606

I have an after-tax IRA and pre-tax IRA. In 2022 I converted $30,000 from the pre-tax IRA to a Roth IRA. I wasn't aware of the pro-rata rule. According to pro-rata rule, I was supposed to convert $4,000 from the after-tax IRA to the Roth IRA. I will convert the $4,000 from the after-tax IRA to the Roth IRA before 10-16-2023.

I already paid estimated tax for the $30,000 in 2022. My questions are: How shall report these 2 conversions on 8606 form? Shall I use one 8606 from for year 2022 for both of them? Or shall use 2 forms: one for year 2022 and another for year 2023?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an after-tax IRA and pre-tax IRA

No, you don't. There's no such thing as "pre-tax" IRA or "after-tax" IRA, there's only... IRA. There are two types of IRA: "Traditional" and "Roth". You're converting from your Traditional IRA to your Roth IRA.

The "A" in IR**A** stands for "**A**rrangement", not "account". It doesn't matter how many different IRA accounts you have, and it doesn't matter where you keep the contributions you've deducted from your taxes ("pre-tax" what you call it), and where you keep the contributions you haven't deducted ("after-tax" in your lingo). From the IRS perspective you only have one IRA with all of these monies combined. Which is why the pro-rata rule exists to begin with.

> How shall report these 2 conversions on 8606 form?

You report on your form 8606 all the conversions for the year, and you need to file a separate form 8606 each year.

For the year 2022 you reported (incorrectly) that you had no basis in your $30K conversion, when in reality the basis was: `"after tax IRA contributions"/total IRA balance * $30000`. You'll need to file an [amended form 8606](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8606#en_US_2022_publink25399ed0e1098). [Follow the instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8606#en_US_2022_publink100020749) for the calculations.

> I will convert the $4,000 from the after-tax IRA to the Roth IRA before 10-16-2023.

That wouldn't matter for the 2022 conversion. But if you still want to do that, you'll do the same math for the $4000 you've converted in 2023.

You may end up with a refund due for 2022 and additional tax due for 2023.

You need to keep track of your basis in the traditional IRA (and file the form 8606 to track it).

Comment: you suggested that the correction is ($30000k = $26500 pre-tax + $3500 after tax) . I suggested that the correction is (total roth conversion $34000 = $30000 pre-tax + $4000 after-tax) (I used rough numbers for explaining). In both cases the pro-rata rule gets applied.  So I thought I can correct the issue by converting $4000 from after-tax ira to roth. is this a valid  correction?  if yes, shall report the $34000 on an amended 8606 for year 2022?  Thanks for the help

Comment: @sami: If you do a conversion in 2023, it's a 2023 conversion. Even if you do it on January 1, 2023, it will still be a 2023 conversion, and need to be reported on the 2023 form 8606, not the 2022 one. The amount of 2022 conversions is $30000. It cannot be changed, because 2022 is over.

Comment: @user102008: your comment means that there are no corrections for such mistakes. right? i can file a 8606 form for 2022 with the right values ($30000k = $26500 pre-tax + $3500 after tax) , but that doesn't reflect the real transaction that i made in 2022. still can't get  a solution for the issue?

Comment: @sami as I said in my answer, you misunderstand how the transactions are perceived by the IRS and the law. There are no separate pre-tax and after-tax IRA accounts. There's just one big bucket of your IRA balances all combined together, from which you withdrew something. The distinction you're making between different accounts is meaningless to the IRS.

Comment: @sami also, I mentioned in the answer, but to point out again: the basis you have in your IRA is based on the **contributions** that were non-deductible. The *earnings* on these contributions (i.e.: the earnings in your "after-tax" account) are not part of your basis and are taxable.

Comment: @sami: to clarify what confuses some people: you can make _contributions_ to an IRA for year Y until April 15 of Y+1, and you can _withdraw an excess contribution_ for Y until Oct. 15 of Y+1, but you can only do a _conversion_ or take a _distribution_ for Y in Y, not one day later.

Comment: @littleadv  , dave_thompson_085 ,  user102008 : Thank you for the help.